# Can I play NOPE on Catomic Bomb?

Tags: exploding-kittens, streaking-kittens

Can I play card 'NOPE' on catomic bomb? isn't too easy that way? I'm wondering.

Answer (score 4):

from the rules [here](https://dumekj556jp75.cloudfront.net/exploding-kittens/English.pdf) on Nope cards

> Stop any action except Exploding Kitten or a Defuse Card.

As Catatonic Bomb is neither of those cards a Nope card can be played.